# Can't install operator_sdk on win10: "cannot use syscall.NsecToFiletime"

Tags: kubernetes, makefile, gnu-make, operator-sdk

I tried following the instructions from the official documentation page of "**Operator SDK**". The device I'm trying to install it on is running on Windows 10, AMD64. I installed GNU Make via Chocolatey.

```
 make --version
GNU Make 4.4.1
Built for Windows32
Copyright (C) 1988-2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

As per the "[Command and install from master](https://sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/installation/#compile-and-install-from-master)" section of the official documentation:

```
git clone https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk
cd operator-sdk
git checkout master
make install
```

The last line "make install" fails:

```
make install
go install -gcflags "all=-trimpath=C:/Users/erjan/Downloads/operator_k8s_sdk" -asmflags "all=-trimpath=C:/Users/erjan/Downloads/operator_k8s_sdk" -ldflags " -X 'github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk/internal/version.Version=v1.31.0+git' -X 'github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk/internal/version.GitVersion=v1.31.0-3-gd21ed649' -X 'github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk/internal/version.GitCommit=d21ed6499ebfc8ecdb4508e1c2a2a0cfd2a151f3' -X 'github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk/internal/version.KubernetesVersion=v1.26.0' -X 'github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk/internal/version.ImageVersion=v1.31.0' "  ./cmd/# github.com/containerd/containerd/archive
..\..\..\go\pkg\mod\github.com\containerd\containerd@v1.4.11\archive\tar_windows.go:234:19: cannot use syscall.NsecToFiletime(hdr.AccessTime.UnixNano()) (value of type syscall.Filetime) as "golang.org/x/sys/windows".Filetime value in struct literal
..\..\..\go\pkg\mod\github.com\containerd\containerd@v1.4.11\archive\tar_windows.go:235:19: cannot use syscall.NsecToFiletime(hdr.ModTime.UnixNano()) (value of type syscall.Filetime) as "golang.org/x/sys/windows".Filetime value in struct literal
..\..\..\go\pkg\mod\github.com\containerd\containerd@v1.4.11\archive\tar_windows.go:236:19: cannot use syscall.NsecToFiletime(hdr.ChangeTime.UnixNano()) (value of type syscall.Filetime) as "golang.org/x/sys/windows".Filetime value in struct literal
..\..\..\go\pkg\mod\github.com\containerd\containerd@v1.4.11\archive\tar_windows.go:239:17: cannot use syscall.NsecToFiletime(hdr.ModTime.UnixNano()) (value of type syscall.Filetime) as "golang.org/x/sys/windows".Filetime value in struct literal
..\..\..\go\pkg\mod\github.com\containerd\containerd@v1.4.11\archive\tar_windows.go:257:27: cannot use syscall.NsecToFiletime(createTime.UnixNano()) (value of type syscall.Filetime) as "golang.org/x/sys/windows".Filetime value in assignment
make: *** [Makefile:75: install] Error 1
```

What could be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see there are several lines where Go is complaining about a type mismatch. Specifically, it is mentioning that `syscall.Filetime` cannot be used as `"golang.org/x/sys/windows".Filetime`.

```
..\..\..\go\pkg\mod\github.com\containerd\containerd@v1.4.11\archive\tar_windows.go:234:19: cannot use syscall.NsecToFiletime(hdr.AccessTime.UnixNano()) (value of type syscall.Filetime) as "golang.org/x/sys/windows".Filetime value in struct literal
```

A value of type `syscall.Filetime` is being used where a value of type `"golang.org/x/sys/windows".Filetime` is expected. This is a type mismatch issue. The file `tar_windows.go` within the `github.com/containerd/containerd` package seems to be the source of these errors, and it appears to be related to how file timestamps are being handled on Windows.

[`containerd/containerd` v1.4.11](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/releases/tag/v1.4.11) seems quite old, considering the [operator-framework/operator-sdk](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk/blob/d21ed6499ebfc8ecdb4508e1c2a2a0cfd2a151f3/go.mod#L72) project itself needs [`containerd` v1.7.0](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/releases/tag/v1.7.0)

Since I got the same error through `make install`, I tried first `go build -a -v ...`, which does not trigger errors.
The Makefile fails on `go install ./cmd/{operator-sdk,helm-operator}`

- `go install ./cmd/helm-operator` works.
- `go install ./cmd/operator-sdk` has the error

That bug is confirmed with your issue [`operator-framework/operator-sdk` issue 6585](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk/issues/6585)

> We do not officially support or build binaries for windows. But we are open to receiving any help with contributions.
> Duplicate of [#6586](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk/issues/6586)
>
> Operator SDK [doesn't officially support or build binaries for Windows](https://sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/overview/#platform-support).
>
> However, there have been instances where users could still build SDK binary from master on their windows machines. This error seems to be coming from `github.com\containerd\containerd@v1.4.11`.
> Looks like it may have an issue. Also, we have explicitly pinned `containerd` to 1.4.11:
>
> [operator-sdk/go.mod](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk/blob/d21ed6499ebfc8ecdb4508e1c2a2a0cfd2a151f3/go.mod#L243):
>
> ```
> github.com/containerd/containerd => github.com/containerd/containerd v1.4.11
> ```
>
> because a bump in it breaks github.com/deislabs/oras.
>
> I would suggest to start by checking if a bump in dependencies fixes these issues without breaking anything else in SDK. If so, we can merge that in master to fix it. Unfortunately, supporting windows builds has not been in our roadmap, but if you would like to try it out, we would appreciate any contributions.

Comment: u mean, i should install golang version 1.19 exactly?   my is go version go1.21.1 windows/amd64

Comment: @ERJAN Actually, no need for Go 1.19. I have edited the answer to include the GitHub issue, which explains why Windows is not supported.

Comment: oh, i opened this issue, but did not receive notification they answered on it. thx, so if i want to write operator using operator sdk i have to install linux in vm ? this is the only option? like virtual box, vmware etc?

Comment: p.s. entire 2 days of work could be saved if i read they dont support windows.

Comment: @ERJAN Yes, a WSL2 Azure-based VM should work nicely.

Answer (score 1):

As @vonc explained, the build errors are caused by containerd v1.4.11 module. It was intentionally set to 1.4.11 in go.mod file with the following comments:

```
// TODO(ryantking): investigate further, v1.5 breaks github.com/deislabs/oras, might be able to update whatever uses the old version of oras
```

After changing containerd version to 1.7.6 in go.mod file, operator sdk can be build successfully. All the unit tests can be passed without any issue.

```
github.com/containerd/containerd => github.com/containerd/containerd v1.7.6
```

There is another warning regarding "sqlite3-binding.c" in building which can be resolved with

```
go env -w CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2 -Wno-return-local-addr"
```

Note: Operator SDK on Windows is not officially supported. While it can be built and run on Windows, there are potential risks of encountering issues and limited support available